# Can anyone share me the sample code in C++ for gSOAP GET method implementation?

Tags: http, methods, get, gsoap

I am new with gSOAP. I am getting the response from server through command prompt and SOAPUI. However I am unable to get response through browser. In browser I am getting response "`GET method not implemented`".

Can anyone please help me to implement get method?

Please share the simple example code where browser also getting correct response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described in the [gSOAP documentaion](http://www.genivia.com/doc/soapdoc2.html#sec:get)

```
struct soap *soap = soap_new();
soap->fget = http_get;
...
soap_serve(soap);
...
int http_get(struct soap *soap)
{
   soap_response(soap, SOAP_HTML); // HTTP response header with text/html
   soap_send(soap, "<HTML>My Web server is operational.</HTML>");
   soap_end_send(soap);
   return SOAP_OK;
}
```